# Problem with a query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to get the job and the deptno 30 from the table but I get an error. Any idea what I am missing?

```
SQL> select deptno from emp where deptno 30;
select deptno from emp where deptno 30
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Table

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate,comm, deptno from emp;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        COMM     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81                    10
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81                    30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81                    10
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81                    20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1400         30
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81        300         30
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81          0         30
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81                    30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81        500         30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81                    20
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80                    20

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        COMM     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09-DEC-82                    20
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12-JAN-83                    20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82                    10

 14 rows selected.
```

Comment: Query doesn't make a whole lot of sense either. If you are selecting the `deptno` where `deptno=30` you know for a fact that all you'll get back are rows saying `30` (if any exist).

Comment: It was something stupid I missed thanks for putting up with my stupid question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you missing the comparison operator (=)?

```
select deptno from emp where deptno=30
```